# turning inline onClick event on off

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing some validation where i need to turn off inline `onClick` event and then turn it on.

Jquery on off method does't work for inline `onClick` event. The line below removes the onClick event. Before this I'm saving event into an array

```
$('.elements a').prop('onclick',null).on('click');
```

Saving events into array

```
    var arr = [];
    var i = 0;
     $('.elements a').each(function(){
        arr[i++] = $(this).attr('onclick');
       });
```

How can I reassign these events in same order to each element. Hope it can be added using `addEventListener` ?

Or is there any other way to achieve the same ?

Comment: As you know Jquery on/off methods, use it. And avoid inline JS, it is bad practice.

Comment: can't remove onClick event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have to use inline events handlers, you can store removed attributes in array and then just reset them back:

```js
var events = $('.elements a').map(function() {
    var onclick = $(this).attr('onclick');
    $(this).removeAttr('onclick');
    return onclick;
}).get();


// ... Apply events later
$('.reset').click(function() {
    $('.elements a').each(function(i) {
     $(this).attr('onclick', events[i])
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elements">
    <a href="#" onclick="console.log(1)">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="console.log(2)">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="console.log(3)">Link 3</a>
</div>

<button class="reset">Reset events</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Javscript solution:

1. Iterate the elements
2. Check if the element `id` exists in a predefined object
3. If it exists, remove the key from the object and re-assign it to the `onclick` event
4. If it doesn't exist, remove the event handler and save it on the object with the element `id` as key

**Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/op6nt25f/**

**Demo Snippet:**

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn'), 
    anchors = document.querySelectorAll('.elements a'), 
    elems = {};
btn.addEventListener('click', toggleClick);

function toggleClick() {
    [].forEach.call(anchors, function(anchor) {
        if (anchor.id in elems) {
            anchor.setAttribute('onclick', elems[anchor.id]);
            delete elems[anchor.id]; 
            btn.innerText = 'Disable click event';
        } else {
            elems[anchor.id] = anchor.getAttribute('onclick');
            anchor.setAttribute('onclick', '');  
            btn.innerText = 'Enable click event';
        }
    });
}

function dojob(elem) { snippet.log(elem.innerText); }
```

```html
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<ul class="elements">
    <li><a id="a1" href="#" onclick="dojob(this)">One</a></li>
    <li><a id="a2" href="#" onclick="dojob(this)">Two</a></li>
    <li><a id="a3" href="#" onclick="dojob(this)">Three</a></li>
    <li><a id="a4" href="#" onclick="dojob(this)">Four</a></li>
</ul>
<button id="btn">Disable click event</button>
```